# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Spark job server

Tags: spark-jobserver

Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Spark job server logs and the job server goes down :

> [2017-06-01 19:09:26,708] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [] [ActorSystem(JobServer)] - Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at spray.http.HttpData$NonEmpty.toByteArray(HttpData.scala:209)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.BasicUnmarshallers$$anon$1.apply(BasicUnmarshallers.scala:30)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.BasicUnmarshallers$$anon$1.apply(BasicUnmarshallers.scala:29)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$3.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:35)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$3.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:34)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$1.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:25)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerLifting$$anon$1.apply(UnmarshallerLifting.scala:24)
>           at spray.httpx.unmarshalling.package$PimpedHttpRequest.as(package.scala:47)
>           at spray.routing.directives.MarshallingDirectives$$anonfun$entity$1.apply(MarshallingDirectives.scala:35)
>           at spray.routing.directives.MarshallingDirectives$$anonfun$entity$1.apply(MarshallingDirectives.scala:35)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$extract$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:86)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$extract$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:86)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:32)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:31)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anonfun$withRejectionHandling$1.applyOrElse(RequestContext.scala:130)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$1.handle(RequestContext.scala:84)
>           at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext.reject(RequestContext.scala:202)
>           at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anon$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:35)

How can i increase its memory?

Comment: try increasing driver memory by using --driver-memory 8g (or whatever value works for you)

Comment: Is it going down after a long run or running a specific program ? what is your current memory allocated to spark job server ?

Comment: It goes down on uploading jar, the jar size is around 350 MB.

Comment: Also it says shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled.

Comment: So i can disable  'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error', but how can i pass memory parameter while uploading the jar to fix heap size error , also i am using java client api for this.